# 2D Orbital Path from State Vectors

Tags: orbital-mechanics, orbit

Given a planet of mass $M$ at the origin, and the state vectors $\textbf{r}$ (in meters) and $\textbf{v}$ (in $m/s$) at time $t = 0$ for a satellite, what are are the equations for:

- Distance $d(t)$ between the satellite and the planet at time $t$, and
- Distance $d(\theta)$ when the satellite is at an angle $\theta$ from "horizontal" (the vector $<1, 0>$)?

Edit: I can already compute certain values, such as the semi-major axis $a$, and the eccentricity $e$. I could even make do with just being able to compute the angle from the horizontal of periapsis.

I'm writing a simple 2d orbital simulator, and I would really like to draw a projected trajectory for the satellite/spaceship that the player is controlling, but I need these formulas to be able to do that. Thanks!

Comment: Not exactly what you're looking for, but related: [How to programmatically calculate orbital elements using position/velocity vectors?](http://space.stackexchange.com/q/1904/29)

Comment: No, I don't think that's what I'm looking for... some of those orbital elements don't apply in 2d; I was hoping that there was a simple formulation for the satellite's path in 2d.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Well, there are quite a few values to compute for the equations. Here is a list of what the symbols mean:

- $\mu$ is the standard gravitational parameter
- **r** is the position vector, whose magnitude $r$ is the current distance from the origin
- **v** is the velocity vector, whose magnitude $v$ is the current speed
- **h** is the angular momentum vector, whose magnitude $h$ is the angular momentum
- **e** is the [eccentricity vector](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eccentricity_vector), whose magnitude is the orbital eccentricity
- $a$ is the semimajor axis
- $\omega$ is argument of periapsis (which in the 2d case is the angle from the $x$-axis of periapsis, measured counterclockwise)
- $\theta$ is the true anomaly
- $\tau$ is the eccentric anomaly
- $M$ is the mean anomaly
- $M_0$ is mean anomaly at periapsis
- $d(\theta)$ is distance of a point on the orbit with a given true anomaly $\theta$
- $d(t)$ is the distance of a point on the orbit at a particular time $t$ (with $t = 0$ giving the periapsis distance)

Now here are the equations to use/solve:
$$\mu = MG$$
$$\textbf{h} = \textbf{r}\times\textbf{v} = \left<0, 0, h\right>, h = x v_y - y v_x$$
$$\textbf{e} = \frac{\textbf{v}\times\textbf{h}}\mu - \frac{\textbf{r}}{|\textbf{r}|} = \left<\frac{v_y h}{\mu} - \frac{x}{r}, -\frac{v_x h}{\mu} - \frac{x}{r}\right>$$
$$e = |\textbf{e}|$$
$$a = \frac{h^2}{\mu(1-e^2)}$$
$$\omega = tan^{-1}\frac{\textbf{e}_y}{\textbf{e}_x}$$
$$d(\theta) = \frac{a(1 - e^2)}{1 + e \cos(\theta + \omega)}$$
$$\tau = \tan^{-1}\frac{\sqrt{1-e^2} \sin\theta}{e+\cos\theta}, \ \theta = 2 \tan^{-1}\left(\sqrt\frac{1+e}{1-e} \tan\frac{\tau}{2}\right)$$
$$M(\tau) = \tau - e \sin \tau$$
$$M_0 = M|_{\tau = \tau(\omega)}$$
$$M(t) = t\sqrt{\frac{G(M + m)}{a^3}}+M_0$$
There isn't a closed form solution for $d(t)$; to compute $d(t)$ at a specific $t$, one must:

- compute mean anomaly $M$ for the given time $t$
- solve for eccentric anomaly $\tau$ in $M = \tau - e \sin \tau$
- compute true anomaly $\theta$ from $\tau$
- and then plug $\theta$ into $d(\theta)$ to get the distance at the angle that corresponds to the given time

Comment: On the third equation, shouldn't that be `y/r` at the very end (instead of `x/r`)?

Comment: For `v×h`, since `h` is a single non-vector value in 2D, is it just multiplication?

Comment: What are all of the values you start with? Which values are stored as the final result of the calculation? What are the words for these values? What is `|r|` and how is it different from `r`? What is the `<,>` notation, a new vector with those components? What handedness do these equations expect? (Godot has the Y axis pointing down)

Comment: How are you supposed to compute true anomaly $\theta$ from $\tau$ if you need $\tau$ but the equation for $\tau$ requires $\theta$ and it's a cyclic dependency?

Comment: @AaronFranke since my answer is pretty old, I don't remember all the details, but let me try to answer your questions. For $v \times h$, it's a cross product, which lies in the $x$,$y$-plane since $h$ lies along the $z$ axis. $\left|r\right|$ is the magnitude (length) of the vector $r$. Indeed the $\left<x,y\right>$ notation describes a vector with those components. The handedness is that $x$ is right and $y$ is up (which is standard in math). The true anomaly $\theta$ can be computed from the eccentric anomaly $\tau$ using the second formula on the fourth-to-last line of formulas.

Comment: @AaronFranke whoops, in my previous comment all the vector should be bolded to be consistent with the answer above. That is, $\textbf{v} \times \textbf{h}$ is a cross product, and the vector $\textbf{h}$ lies along the $z$ axis. The vector $\textbf{r}$ has magnitude $\left|\textbf{r}\right| = r$.

Comment: But h is not a vector, it is a scalar value. The cross product of a 2D vector is a single number.

Comment: @AaronFranke indeed, $\textbf{h}$ is the vector, and $h$ is its $z$-value. That is, we have $\textbf{h} = \left<0, 0, h\right>$. The cross product exists in 3d but not 2d, so when we take the cross product of $\textbf{r}$ and $\textbf{v}$ we get a 3d vector $\textbf{h} = \textbf{r} \times \textbf{v}$ which lies along the $z$-axis.

Comment: Could you put down the meaning of the symbols you use? I was looking at the wikipedia on orbital elements, but I can't make sense of elements like $\omega$ in the 2D case. What is $\mathbf e$? I can only find the eccentricity on wikipedia, but it should be a scalar.

Comment: Sure, let me try to find sources for all of the equations. (It's been a while, so hopufully I remember what they mean!):

- *r* is the position vector
- *v* is the velocity vector
- *h* is the angular momentum vector
- *e* is the [eccentricity vector](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eccentricity_vector), whose magnitude is the orbital eccentricity
- $a$ is the semimajor axis
- $\omega$ is argument of periapsis
- $\theta$ is the true anomaly
- $\tau$ is the eccentric anomaly
- $M$ is the mean anomoly

Comment: Some tips:When "r" is in italics, he means magnitude of the vector r.  x and y imply r.x and r.y, In the calculation of e, the second x/r should be y/r,  use atan2(y,x) instead of atan(y/x) and it will save you a lot of headache around quadrants.

Answer (score 3):

With $M$, $\textbf{r}$, $\textbf{v}$, you can calculate the specific energy, $\mathcal{E}$ and specific angular momentum of the object, $\mathcal{M}$, which are constants of the orbital motion.  From those you can get the semi-major axis, $a$, and the eccentricity, $e$.  That is all you need in two dimensions.

That won't get you a closed form solution for $d(t)$.  What you *can* get are parametric solutions in the form $t(\tau)$, $r(\tau)$, and $\phi(\tau)$ (or $x(\tau)$ and $y(\tau)$), which can be used for making plots.  $\tau$ is the [eccentric anomaly](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eccentric_anomaly), which for an elliptical orbit is the angle of the position from the center of the ellipse (*not* the focus of the ellipse, where the planet is).  When you run $\tau$ from $0$ to $2\pi$, you get a complete orbit.  The equations are (where $r$ is the magnitude of $\textbf{r}$ (what you're calling "$d$"), and $\mu$ is $GM$:

$r(\tau)=a\left(1-e\cos{\tau}\right)$

$\phi(\tau)=\tan^{-1}\left(\cos{\tau}-e,\sqrt{1-e^2}\sin{\tau}\right)$

$t(\tau)=\sqrt{a^3\over\mu}\left(\tau-e \sin{\tau}\right)$

The argument order for the two-parameter inverse tangent above is $\tan^{-1}\left(x,y\right)$.  Many programming languages have an `atan2(y,x)` function with the arguments in the other order, so be careful lest you cause havoc in the heavens.

You will need to solve for $\tau_0$, e.g. using $r(\tau_0)=r_0$ to know where your starting point is in the orbit, if that matters for your plot.  You may also want to add an offset to $\phi$ to get the orbit rotated to some specific starting location, again if that matters to you.

By the way, it is common to use $\mu$ instead of $M$ because we can usually measure $\mu$ to much higher accuracy than we currently know the fundamental physical constant $G$.  So how well we know $M$ for a body is usually limited by how well we know $G$.

Answer (score 2):

I won't solve 100% of this for you, but I'll give you enough to figure it out. From [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elliptic_orbit)

$v=\sqrt{\mu\left({2\over{r}}-{1\over{a}}\right)}$

Where

$\mu=GM$

From these, G is a constant, M is the mass. You provide then every term in that equation except for $a$. Simply back out what $a$ is, and you know the orbital velocity at for any given distance. The next thing to know is the orbital period. That can be found, according to [Wikipedia/ Kepler's Third Law](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orbital_period), to be:

$T = 2\pi\sqrt{a^3/\mu}$

You know all of these values already. Last piece of information is [Kepler's Second Law](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kepler%27s_laws_of_planetary_motion). Put it all together, and you should be able to piece together the formula.

Comment: I'm afraid I don't understand. I can compute the velocity at any distance ($r$, correct?), but how do I determine at what angle the max-velocity (periapsis) is? That's really all I need.