# How can I plot a precessing orbital plane of an artificial satellite on a polar plot from a TLE in Python?

Tags: artificial-satellite, low-earth-orbit, two-line-elements, python, space-track

How can I plot the orbital plane of an artificial satellite on a polar plot from a TLE in Python?

Very new to all of this. As I understand it I need to extract TLE's from Space-track.org. Then use this TLE to create a plot of the orbit plane in a polar plot.

I'm looking in particular at the CHAMP satellite. The orbit plane itself changes as a function of time so ideally I would also like to plot the progression of this orbit plane as a function of time. I.e. snapshots of the orbit plane at certain times.

If you need any clarification or have any questions please ask. Any help would be greatly appreciated thanks!

Comment: [This answer](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/25958/12102) shows how plot one *orbit* from one TLE using Python. You would have to modify it to show a plane rather than the orbit, and then run it at regular intervals to generate a sequence of planes. However, you may need to use multiple TLEs since their predictive accuracy degrades quickly with time.