# Object slowest at periapsis - despite correct position calculation

Tags: orbital-mechanics, mathematics, simulation, astrodynamics

I'm coding up a simulation of celestial bodies using patched conics. At the moment I'm stuck with calculating the velocity of the object in the perifocal frame.

For the position I'm simply using the [orbit equation](https://orbital-mechanics.space/the-orbit-equation/the-orbit-equation.html#equation-eq-scalar-orbit-equation)

$$
r = \frac{h^2}{\mu}\frac{1}{1 + e\cos{v}}
$$

where $h$ is the angular momentum, $\mu$ is the standard gravitational parameter, $e$ is eccentricity, $v$ is true anomaly.

I then take the cosine and sine of $v$ to get the exact point in the perifocal frame, so
$$
p = r\sin v
$$
$$
q = r\cos v
$$

It makes sense to me then that $\frac{dp}{dv}$ and $\frac{dq}{dv}$ would give me the velocity components.

So I take the derivative (using Wolfram Alpha) and arrive at the following

$$
\frac{dr\sin v}{dv} = \frac{h^2(\cos v + e)}{\mu(1 + e \cos v)^2}
$$
$$
\frac{dr\cos v}{dv} = -\frac{h^2\sin v}{\mu(1 + e\cos v)^2}
$$

which simplify to

$$
\frac{dr\sin v}{dv} = \frac{r (\cos v + e)}{1 + e\cos v}
$$

$$
\frac{dr\cos v}{dv} = -\frac{r \sin v}{1 + e\cos v}
$$

But putting these to use the positions appear to work as expected. **But velocity is the lowest at the periapsis and highest at the apoapsis**. Which I know shouldn't be the case.

The same behaviour appears if I just approximate the velocity as $p(v) - p(v + 0.001)$

Is there anything wrong with my calculations or assumptions?

Comment: The equation you've used only gives you information about the _shape_ of the orbit.  It  looks like you're assuming a constant angular vellocity, which is definitely not the case in non-circular orbits.

Comment: You may find this helpful: https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/675868/123208 & https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/748130/123208 which have the vis-viva equation in terms of true anomaly, and some other related stuff about angular velocity and specific angular momentum.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As uhoh said, the velocity is the derivative of the position w.r.t. to time, not true anomaly. I.e., if we denote time by $t$, the components of the velocity vector are $\left(\frac{dp}{dt}, \frac{dq}{dt}\right) = \left(\frac{dp}{dv}\frac{dv}{dt}, \frac{dq}{dv}\frac{dv}{dt}\right)$. Fortunately, $\frac{dv}{dt}$ is just the angular speed, equal to $\frac{h}{r^2}$ (because the specific angular momentum $h$ is equal to $r\text{v}_\perp$, where $\text{v}_\perp$ is the transversal speed, and $\text{v}_\perp = r\frac{dv}{dt}$).

So the actual velocity components are
$$
\frac{dp}{dt} = \frac{r (\cos v + e)}{1 + e\cos v}\frac{h}{r^2} = \frac{\mu}{h} (\cos v + e)
$$
and
$$
\frac{dq}{dt} = -\frac{r \sin v}{1 + e\cos v}\frac{h}{r^2} = -\frac{\mu}{h} \sin v.
$$

Comment: Thanks! This helped a lot!

Answer (score 11):

If I understand correctly, your $p, q$ are essentially cartesian coordinates, and you're trying to get the velocity components in those two orthogonal directions.

However, you're taking the derivative with respect to [true anomaly](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/True_anomaly) $v$, and $v$ does not increase linearly with time for non-circular orbits. It's [mean anomaly](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mean_anomaly) that does that. While there is a [transcendental relationship between the two](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mean_anomaly#Formulae), they are not interchangeable.

Things like $r(t)$ and $v(t)$ have no simple solution that you can just differentiate to get velocity.

However you have two other ways to get velocity.

1. The [vis-viva equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vis-viva_equation) will give you speed v (not your $v$) as a direct function of $r$ (via conservation laws) and you can apply that speed tangent to the ellipse to get the velocity vector.

$$\text{v}^2 = GM \left(\frac{2}{r} - \frac{1}{a} \right)$$

2. Luckily for us while $r(t)$ and $v(t)$ don't have simple solutions, their inverse $t(r)$ and $t(v)$ do! See:

- [this answer to *Solution to two-body problem in orbital mechanics for r(t) and theta(t), rather than r(theta)?*](https://space.stackexchange.com/a/61801/12102)
- [this answer to *What is the analytical closed-form solution of the two-body problem to verify its numerical integration results?*](https://space.stackexchange.com/a/43237/12102)

Comment: $\frac{dv}{dt}$ (i.e., the angular speed) is $\frac{h}{r^2}$. The OP just needs to multiply the answer by this to get the correct velocity components.

Comment: @Litho I don't know what $h$ is and I'm not an orbital mechanic. Please consider writing a short answer post so that folks will see it. *Thanks!*