# Satellite Ground Track From ECEF Frame Position And Velocity Vector

Tags: ground-track

The above question may sound naive. I am trying to understand how satellite ground track can be computed when satellite position and velocity vectors are available from on-board GPS receiver of a low earth orbiting satellite.

Comment: [Here](http://space.stackexchange.com/a/1919/9060) is half of the answer - the other half is converting from ECEF to ECI.

Comment: @ Chris I got the conversion from ECI state vectors to keplerian elements. But how to convert state vector ECEF frame to ECI frame.