# Trouble understanding the memorandum "Cartesian State Vectors → Keplerian Orbit Elements"

Tags: orbital-mechanics, orbital-elements, orbital, position

So, I was reading [this memorandum](https://downloads.rene-schwarz.com/download/M002-Cartesian_State_Vectors_to_Keplerian_Orbit_Elements.pdf) to make some c# classes helping with keplerian/newtonian orbital simulations. Then, I found this weird piece for solving for $n$...

$n = (0, 0, 1)^T × h = (−h_y, h_x, 0)^T$

The paradox is, it doesn't mention any variable T beforehand. An answer that just solves the problem this part of the paper addresses (part c) works too.

In that case, we have the following given values:

The relative positional vector $r$
The velocity vector $r˙$
The standard gravitational parameter $µ$
The orbital momentum vector $h$
The eccentricity vector $ɛ$

and we want to find...

The vector $n$ pointing towards the ascending node
The true anomaly $v$

I saw [this post](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/25661/help-with-cartesian-state-vectors-%E2%86%92-keplerian-orbit-elements-c), but it didn't explain everything for me.

Any help appreciated. Sorry for my slightly bizzare wording.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That T is not a variable.  It indicates that you should take the *matrix transpose* of those row vectors, making them into column vectors.

Comment: Ah, weird formatting.